# ScrollView stickyHeaderIndices prop does not work as expected with multiple children

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using the ScrollView component and i want to have multiple sticky items while scrolling

```
      <ScrollView
        style={style.someStyles}
        stickyHeaderIndices={[0, 1]}
      >
```

But what happens is only the last element gets sticked to the top and the other one doesn't

Any workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

Just try this: `stickyHeaderIndices={[1, 0]}`

Answer (score 1):

You could just wrap both of your components inside a view and just pass one value to your sticky header:

```
<ScrollView
    style={style.someStyles}
    stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}>
  <View>
    <Component1 />
    <Component2 />
  </View>
</ScrollView>
```